# How to add different padding between strings

Tags: swiftui

I want to add different padding between strings in SwiftUI.

```
private let title: String
private let descriptions: [String]
private let type: RCHSelectorType
private let amountOfBPs: Int
public init(title: String = "Alexandru", descriptions: [String] = ["Subtitle1", "Subtitle2"], type: RCHSelectorType = .bpSmall, amountOfBPs: Int = 2) {
  self.descriptions = descriptions
  self.type = type
  self.amountOfBPs = amountOfBPs
  if amountOfBPs > 1 && type != .bpSmall {
    self.title = "\(title) +\(amountOfBPs)"
  } else {
    self.title = title
  }
}
```

If the type is different from bpSmall, I want to add 5 padding after the title and 10 padding after the + sign, but can not find a way how to do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: Did you try to concatenate multiple Text views with different trailing padding?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:swiftui], but there is no SwiftUI code in your question. Please edit your question to include the SwiftUI code that draws the title.

Comment: Can't you just use an HStack with spacing acording to your case ?
Also what comes after texts ?